# Where to obtain the certificate signing response in ping federate?

Tags: pingfederate

I am able to generate certificate signing reply in ping federate. When I try to import the same CSR file as a response, I am getting error.

Please help.

Thanks,
Aswini J

Comment: Please provide a better description of what you are trying to do and have done and where it is failing as it is not clear at all from your question. I'm guessing you are trying to generate a CSR for your Digital Signing Certificate. Start with the documentation and then let us know what part of this isn't working.  http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF72/Digital+Signing+and+Decryption+Keys+and+Certificates

Comment: I have read the documentation. Only then I started doing it. For every certificate, there is an option called certificate signing. When I clicked on it,   there are two options: a)Generate Certificate signing Request b)Import certificate signing Response. It is easier to do option a. But I found no option for generating Certificate signing Response. Should I export the CSR generated and import the same as the response? or Is there any option? Thanks.

Comment: The only reason you would need to do this if you are exporting Cert to get it signed by a 3rd Party Certificate Authority.  Regardless, you need to have a Certificate Authority sign it before you import the signed Cert Signing Response. PingFederate is not a Certificate Authority so it cannot sign the Request. If you have already done this, ensure that PingFederate has the public key of the Root Certificate Authority in its Trusted CA store.